# Flot and OrderBars plugin bars stacking

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, flot, kibana

So we have a Kibana application that is displaying several graphs, and on one we are trying to use the orderBars plugin. It doesn't work 90% of the time, the bars appear stacked on top of each other, instead of next to each other, occasionally with the right gust of wind and panel refresh, it will show properly. I'm fairly sure its an issue with requireJS but I'm having difficulty tracking it down.

Below is the code that is creating the bars:

```
//This is the first few lines of the orderBars plugin:

(function($){
    console.log(plot);
    function init(plot){
```

Logging plot here comes back undefined. This leads me to believe that jquery.flot is not being loaded before orderBars, but in the requireJS config we are requiring flot as a dependency to orderbars, and have even tried adding it to that require function as well shown below, to no avail.

```
//THIS IS THE PANEL Module.js, note that they don't define the flot items at the top. Unsure why not, adding them there doesn't see to fix or break anything.

define([
  'angular',
  'app',
  'lodash',
  'jquery',
  'kbn'
],
function (angular, app, _, $, kbn) {

...

 // Populate element.
      require(['jquery.flot', 'jquery.flot.orderBars'], function(){

        // Populate element
        try {
          // Add plot to scope so we can build out own legend
          if ((scope.panel.chart === 'bar') || (scope.panel.chart === 'line')) {
            plot = $.plot(elem, chartData, options);
          }
          // Populate legend
          if(elem.is(":visible")){
            setTimeout(function(){
              scope.legend = plot.getData();
              if(!scope.$$phase) {
                scope.$apply();
              }
            });
          }
        } catch(e) {
          elem.text(e);
        }
      });
```

Any Ideas would be a great help. Thank you

[image: Stacked Bars]

**EDIT** Requested requireJS config, and updated moduleJS top to show defines. Forgive formatting. Also, if you see something wrong, please let me know, I didn't write most of this and want to make sure it's right, haven't been working with requireJS long.

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'app',
  urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
  paths: {
    config:                   '../config',
    settings:                 'components/settings',
    kbn:                      'components/kbn',

    vendor:                   '../vendor',
    css:                      '../vendor/require/css',
    text:                     '../vendor/require/text',
    moment:                   '../vendor/moment',
    blob:                     '../vendor/blob',
    filesaver:                '../vendor/filesaver',
    chromath:                 '../vendor/chromath',
    angular:                  '../vendor/angular/angular',
    'angular-cookies':        '../vendor/angular/angular-cookies',
    'angular-dragdrop':       '../vendor/angular/angular-dragdrop',
    'angular-strap':          '../vendor/angular/angular-strap',
    'angular-sanitize':       '../vendor/angular/angular-sanitize',
    timepicker:               '../vendor/angular/timepicker',
    datepicker:               '../vendor/angular/datepicker',
    bindonce:                 '../vendor/angular/bindonce',

    lodash:                   'components/lodash.extended',
    'lodash-src':             '../vendor/lodash',
    bootstrap:                '../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap',

    jquery:                   '../vendor/jquery/jquery-1.8.0',
    'jquery-ui':              '../vendor/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3',

    'extend-jquery':          'components/extend-jquery',

    'jquery.flot':            '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot',
    'jquery.flot.pie':        '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.pie',
    'jquery.flot.events':     '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.events',
    'jquery.flot.selection':  '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.selection',
    'jquery.flot.stack':      '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.stack',
    'jquery.flot.stackpercent':'../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.stackpercent',
    'jquery.flot.time':       '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.time',
    'jquery.flot.byte':       '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.byte',
    'jquery.flot.orderBars':  '../vendor/jquery/jquery.flot.orderBars',
    'jquery.odoticker':       '../vendor/jquery/jquery.odoticker',

    modernizr:                '../vendor/modernizr-2.6.1',
    numeral:                  '../vendor/numeral',
    jsonpath:                 '../vendor/jsonpath',
    elasticjs:                '../vendor/elasticjs/elastic-angular-client',

    'jspdf':                  '../vendor/jspdf/jspdf',
    'swfobject':              '../vendor/jspdf/swfobject',
    'downloadify':            '../vendor/jspdf/downloadify.min',

    'h2c':                          '../vendor/jspdf/html2canvas',
    'c2h':                          '../vendor/jspdf/canvas2image',
    'png':                          '../vendor/jspdf/png',
    'zlib':                         '../vendor/jspdf/zlib',
    'addimg':                   '../vendor/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage',
    'pngSup':                   '../vendor/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.png_support',
    'base64':                                 '../vendor/jspdf/base64'
},
shim: {
angular: {
  deps: ['jquery','config'],
  exports: 'angular'
},

bootstrap: {
  deps: ['jquery']
},

modernizr: {
  exports: 'Modernizr'
},

jsonpath: {
  exports: 'jsonPath'
},

jquery: {
  exports: 'jQuery'
},

// simple dependency declaration
//
'jquery-ui':            ['jquery'],
'jquery.flot':          ['jquery'],
'jquery.flot.byte':     ['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.orderBars':['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.pie':      ['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.events':   ['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.selection':['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.stack':    ['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.stackpercent':['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],
'jquery.flot.time':     ['jquery', 'jquery.flot'],

'angular-sanitize':     ['angular'],
'angular-cookies':      ['angular'],
'angular-dragdrop':     ['jquery','jquery-ui','angular'],
'angular-loader':       ['angular'],
'angular-mocks':        ['angular'],
'angular-resource':     ['angular'],
'angular-route':        ['angular'],
'angular-touch':        ['angular'],
'bindonce':             ['angular'],
'angular-strap':        ['angular', 'bootstrap','timepicker', 'datepicker'],

timepicker:             ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
datepicker:             ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],

elasticjs:              ['angular', '../vendor/elasticjs/elastic'],

'jspdf':                 ['jquery'],
'swfobject':             ['jspdf'],
'downloadify':           ['jspdf'],

'h2c':                   ['jspdf', 'base64', 'c2h'],
'c2h':                   ['jspdf', 'base64'],
'zlib':                  ['jspdf'],
'addimg':                ['jspdf', 'base64'],
'pngSup':                ['jspdf']
},
 waitSeconds: 60
 });
```

Comment: The `require` call you show won't guarantee any order between the two modules. Please add your RequireJS config to your question.

Comment: Updated per your request, in the dependecy section of the require.config.js I have flot as a requirement for the orderbars plugin

Comment: Yes, but jQuery 1.8.0 does not need a `shim`. Specifying a `shim` for a module that calls `define` can yield undefined behavior so you should remove the `shim` config for the `jquery` module. It is not clear to me though whether the undefined behavior that it may cause would cause the problem you've run into.

Comment: Removed the shim, thanks for that, but didn't affect my problem.